# HTML5 document outline reusable components

Tags: javascript, html

According to: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Sections_and_Outlines_of_an_HTML5_document

> Sections and Outlines of an HTML5 Document
>
> An exception to the rule of thumb that heading rank should match the
>   section nesting level is for sections that may be reused in multiple
>   documents. For example, a section might be stored in a
>   content-management system and assembled into documents at run time. In
>   this case, a good practice is to start at h1 for the top heading
>   level of the reusable section. The nesting level of the reusable
>   section will be determined by the section hierarchy of the document in
>   which it appears. Explicit section tags are still helpful in this
>   case.

How can we respect the document outline with HTML4 for reusable components?
E.g. the reusable components is created with h1, but it should have the context h3 when embedded within a certain template.
Is there another way than using Javascript for backwards compatibility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always change the stored `<h1>` to the one that matches your actual nesting level using client-side javascript, since web crawlers should already handle well multiple `<h1>`s, so theoretically you are good to go.

In reality some web crawlers still can't understand document outlines, so as well as for SEO reasons as for common sense it might be better to store your components right away with the respective header level, allowing both old crawlers and old browsers to render it right away.

As of document outline you are still good to go because in every sectioning element the first header element of any level will be the header of that section as every same or upper level of heading will open a new implied sectioning.

The only problem with this is in case you will want to use any of the reusable sections outside it's old nesting level, resulting in wrong html outline as far as old browsers and old crawlers are concerned.

This obviously can't be resolved with client-side javascript as crawlers usually don't execute it, but instead should be done on server side at the time of assembling the components changing the heading levels of the reusable component (maybe by passing the initial level to the assembler as parameter), to match it's ancestors sublevel.

Comment: Thanks for great explanation. I think that I'll create scripts to manipulate the templates with Node at the server, specifically to manage the doc outline.

Comment: Ah yeah, Node, that's actually JS too, edited the answer to clarify that I'm referring to client-side JS.